# Is there a non-constant function on the sphere that diagonalizes all rotations simultaneously?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis, unitary-representations

**INTRODUCTION**. I am teaching a course in Harmonic Analysis. In class, very often I find myself stressing out the fundamental property that the functions
$$
e_n(x)=\exp(2\pi i n x), \quad \text{where }\quad x\in \mathbb R / \mathbb Z$$
are simultaneous eigenfunctions of all translations. By this I mean that, defining
$$\label{1}\tag{1}
\tau_y f(x):=f(x-y), \quad \text{for }x, y\in\mathbb R/ \mathbb Z$$
it holds that
$$\label{2}\tag{2}
\tau_y e_n=\lambda_{y,n}e_n, \quad \text{for all }y\in\mathbb R/\mathbb Z.$$

---

**QUESTION**. Let us now replace $\mathbb R/\mathbb Z$ with the sphere $\mathbb S^2$. By analogy with (1), define
$$
\tau_A f(\omega):=f(A^{-1}\omega), \quad \text{for }A\in \mathrm{SO}(3),\ \omega\in\mathbb S^2.$$
Is there a non-constant $f\in L^2(\mathbb S^2)$ such that
$$\label{3}\tag{3}
\tau_Af=\lambda_A f, \quad \text{for all }A\in \mathrm{SO}(3)?$$

---

**REMARKS**. From a more general standpoint, the simultaneous diagonalization property \eqref{2} of $e_n$ is a common feature of all locally compact abelian groups. Indeed, if $G$ denotes such a group, then we can define
$$
\tau_g f(h):=f(g^{-1}h), \quad g,h\in G,\ f\in L^2(G), $$
yielding a unitary representation of $G$. And since $G$ is abelian, all irreducible subrepresentations must be one-dimensional, or in other words, they must be eigenspaces of all $\tau_g$ simultaneously. This is precisely the diagonalization phenomenon observed above in the case $G=\mathbb R / \mathbb Z$.

The present question occured to me while I was trying to find a concrete, pedagogical example of the failure of this simultaneous diagonalization in the non-abelian case.

---

**ANSWER**. I can actually provide an answer to the question, which unfortunately I find unsatisfactory for reasons that I will explain below. The answer is the following.

We claim that no non-constant function $f$ satisfying \eqref{3} exists. To prove this, introduce the projectors
$$ P_{n} f(\omega):=\int_{\mathbb S^2} f(\nu)L_n(\omega\cdot \nu)\ d\sigma(\nu),$$
where $L_n$ is the Legendre polynomial of degree $n$, with an appropriate normalization (the exact value of which is irrelevant here). For each $n\in \mathbb N_{\ge 0}$, $P_n f$ is a spherical harmonic of degree $n$. It is clear that $P_n$ commutes with $\tau_A$ for all $A\in\mathrm{SO}(3)$, so by \eqref{3}
$$
\tau_A\left( P_n f\right) = P_n \tau_Af= \lambda_AP_n f. $$
So, if a non-constant $f$ satisfying the property \eqref{3} existed, we could find a spherical harmonic $Y_n=P_n f$ of degree $n>0$ that satisfies the same property. But this cannot be, for in that case $Y_n$ would span an irreducible subrepresentation of the space $\mathbb{Y}_n$ of spherical harmonics of degree $n$ and we know that $\mathbb{Y}_n$ is irreducible.

The only possibility is that $f$ is a constant, for in that case $P_n f=0$ except for $n=0$. $\Box$

---

**CONCLUDING REMARK**. The answer provided above is unsatisfactory for my teaching purposes, since it is too technical and requires the introduction of several concepts, such as spherical harmonics and irreducible subrepresentations. Ideally, I would like an answer that is geometrical in nature and which directly exposes the role of the non-Abelianity of $SO(3)$.

Comment: Sorry I confused things. What I should actually say is this: if there would be such a function, it would provide a nontrivial 1-dimensional representation of $SO(3)$, hence a nontrivial homomorphism from $SO(3)$ to the multiplicative group, which does not exist since abelianization of $SO(3)$ is trivial.

Comment: In other words, just noncommutativity does not suffice to rule out existence of such functions.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: I see. So a non-abelian group with non-trivial abelianization could support such simultaneous eigenfunctions, I gather. Could you make a concrete example, as simple as possible? Would something like $SO(3)\times \mathbb R$ work?

Comment: No, if the group contains $SO(3)$ the common eigenfunction would be also common for $SO(3)$. However $SO(3)$ has nonabelian subgroups with common eigenfunctions. Generate e. g. the subgroup by arbitrary rotations around the $z$ axis together with $(x,y,z)\mapsto(y,x,-z)$. For it, $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2$ and $f(x,y,z)=z^2$ are common eigenfunctions, for example.

Comment: Another example of such subgroup in $SO(3)$ is the (finite) rotation symmetry group of the (standardly situated) cube: it has common eigenfunctions $xyz$, $(x^2-y^2)(x^2-z^2)(y^2-z^2)$, $x^4+y^4+z^4$, ...

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: thank you very much for these beautiful examples. If you could make those into an answer I would gladly upvote it. That would not be precisely an answer to the present question, but I think it would be extremely interesting anyway.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე It depends on what space $SO(3) \times \mathbb R$ is acting on. If it's acting on $\mathbb R^3$, with $\mathbb R$ acting by scaling, then the functions $x \mapsto |x|^{\alpha}$ would be examples - not incredibly nontrivial, but still useful for many purposes in mathematics.

Comment: @WillSawin Yes, thanks! I should clarify that I have in mind the same action when restricted to $SO(3)$

Comment: Offering what I think is an accurate, and not toooo onerous, reframing: I tell my beginning students that the generalization to non-abelian (e.g., finite, if we want to avoid some complications, both analytical and algebraic) groups, of the notion of "simultaneous eigenvector" is "irreducible repn". I use this as a _motivation_ for (a bit of) repn theory, since, after all, it's the answer to a question. The sphere case is probably the simplest with a physical sense, although there is a bit of analysis... I tell my students that people have known this case for 200+ years. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett: (This is not totally related, but let me take the opportunity to tell you that I loved your lecture notes on "functions on circles", when I first studied Harmonic Analysis. Thanks a lot for making those public). More on point, I like the idea of looking at finite non-abelian groups. That sure avoids unnecessary complications and makes available algorithmical exercises. It gives a really algebraic flavor to the course, though.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro, thanks for the positive feedback! :) :)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე (How) do the eigenfunctions of the rotation symmetry group of the cube $xyz, (x^2-y^2)(x^2-z^2)(y^2-z^2), x^4+y^4+z^4$ relate with the number of ways we can [color](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma#Colorings_of_a_cube) the cube using the Burnside's lemma?

Comment: @Dabed I am not sure but I guess connection is like this. You may view colorings as functions constant inside each face separately and along all edges collectively. Clearly your group acts on such functions, and the task is to enumerate orbits of this action. Now *any* function can be obtained, in a certain sense uniquely, from eigenfunctions.  But the eigenfunctions I listed are polynomial, while for colorings you need piecewise constant ones. How to get the latter from the former, I don't know.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე ah I see I just thought maybe the permutations that left a particular polynomial invariant corresponded with a particular orbit of the colorings or something like that, I (clearly) don't understand much so will have to learn and think more about it, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dabed While there are lots of representations, you have only so many stabilizers of points since they are all subgroups of your group. So in general only knowing the collection of stabilizers that occur does not provide enough information. This can be also seen from the formula in Burnside's lemma: it needs information about the sets of the form $X^g$ (collection of elements of $X$ stabilized by any given $g\in G$) rather than about $G^x$ (collection of elements of the group stabilizing any given $x\in X$). Unlike $G^x$ I don't see how to relate those $X^g$ for polynomials and for colorings

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე thanks!, ok so if I got it right then when I'm counting colorings I'm counting element of X that are left unchanged by an action g whereas when I'm counting the permutations of a polynomial what I'm really counting is rather the actions of G that that make no change for an element x, and I was confusing both of them.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

For $\mathrm{C}^1$-functions, the argument can be reduced to the circle case: Write the sphere as a union of circles meeting at the poles. On each circle the considered function is equivariant under all rotations, therefore its restriction to the circle must be of the form $t\mapsto C\exp(i\lambda t)$ for some real numbers $C,\lambda$. Since the circles meet at the poles and the function is continuously differentiable, the $C$'s and $\lambda$'s agree for all the circles. To see that $\lambda$ must be zero, apply the argument again with a different choice of poles, for example a pair of antipodal points in the original equator.

Comment: "Write the sphere as a union of circles meeting at poles" means that the circles are meridians, I guess. Like in the following image: https://home.csulb.edu/~rodrigue/geog140/meridian.jpg Is this right?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: yes.

Answer (score 12):

For a non-abelian group $G$ acting on a space $X$, such a function would have to be invariant under the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ of $G$, and thus constant on the orbits of the commutator subgroup.

So the size of the orbits of the commutator subgroup gives a measure of how boring such a function must be. (One can probably prove that this is sharp - that for a compact group $G$ and a reasonable space $X$ a smooth function constant on $[G,G]$-orbits can be approximated by a sum of eigenfunctions - by reducing to Fourier analysis on $G^{ab}$ and various quotients of it.)

For $G= SO(3)$ and $X=S^2$ the whole space is a single orbit of the commutator subgroup so such orbits must be constant.

But for $SO(3)$ acting on other spaces, like $\mathbb R^3$, there are many more such functions.

Comment: The opposite extreme is when $[G, G]=\{1\}$, for in that case the orbits are singletons, and this argument places no obstructions on eigenfunctions. Your answer is a really nice observation, thank you for it. I also discovered that $[SO(3), SO(3)]=SO(3)$. Actually, $SO(3)$ has no nontrivial normal subgroups, something that I had never seriously thought about before. By the way, this is exactly what is suggested in comments to the main question (through the fact that the abelianization of $SO(3)$ is trivial).

Answer (score 8):

As requested by the OP, I am making an answer from my comments to the question.

This is all standard material but I agree with him that it might be useful for somebody interested in this material.

Still, it might be better to migrate the whole stuff to math.SE. Please just vote for it if you think so.

Given any function $f$ on $\mathbb S^2$ with $\tau_A(f)=\lambda_Af$ for all $A\in\operatorname{SO}(3)$ as in the question, we will have$$f(Av)=\tau_{A^{-1}}(f)(v)=\lambda_{A^{-1}}f(v)$$for all $A$ and $v$, where we identify $\mathbb S^2$ with the set of all unit length vectors.

It follows that $f(ABv)=f(BAv)$ for all $A,B\in\operatorname{SO}(3)$ and all $v\in\mathbb S^2$.

This implies that $f$ is a constant function. Indeed given any unit vectors $v_1$, $v_2$, there is a $B\in\operatorname{SO}(3)$ with $v_2=Bv_1$. Let $v$ be a unit vector along the rotation axis of $B$, i. e. such that $Bv=v$; then there is an $A\in\operatorname{SO}(3)$ with $v_1=Av$. Then,
$$
f(v_1)=f(Av)=f(ABv)=f(BAv)=f(Bv_1)=f(v_2).
$$

This argument clearly depends on noncommutativity of $\operatorname{SO}(3)$, but not only on noncommutativity. Rather, declaring $AB=BA$ for all $A$, $B$ collapses $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ to the trivial group, i. e. $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ is a perfect group, which is stronger than just noncommutativity.

For example, the subgroup of $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ generated by all rotations around the $z$ axis together with the transformation sending $(x,y,z)$ to $(y,x,-z)$ (i. e. the $180^\circ$ rotation around the axis $(t,t,0)$) is noncommutative — it is the (continually) infinite dihedral group — but it admits a nonconstant eigenfunction $f(x,y,z)=z$.

For another example, the group of rotations of the unit cube is a noncommutative subgroup of order $24$ in $\operatorname{SO}(3)$ which has common eigenfunctions $f(x,y,z)=xyz$, $(x^2-y^2)(x^2-z^2)(y^2-z^2)$, $x^4+y^4+z^4$.

Just for fun, here are the level lines of these functions on $\mathbb S^2$, clearly exhibiting cubical symmetry:

$xyz$

[image]

$(x^2-y^2)(x^2-z^2)(y^2-z^2)$

[image]

$x^4+y^4+z^4$

[image]

Comment: This is really interesting, also pedagogically. As Paul Garrett suggests in comments (to the main question), looking at $SO(3)$ introduces technical complications, since it is an infinite group. But here you are looking at finite groups, and you are getting interesting applications and beautiful pictures. Thanks!

Comment: I presented this material in class yesterday. I think it was the best lecture in Harmonic Analysis I ever gave. The students were all super attentive. Thank you VERY much.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro The pleasure is mine - I am very glad I've been useful